# Use CSS with input inside label

Tags: html, css, input, label

Is it possible to point CSS class to label when input radio are checked with this markup?

```html
<label class="container">
   <span class="radio">
     <input name="size" type="radio">
   </span> 
</label>
```

Comment: What is it that you try to achieve?

Comment: No you would need to have the label as a sibling - or put a span next to the input and style that instead

Comment: This `label:has(input:checked)` seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/mtf850qs/ ... but do note that `has()` isn't fully supported: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: @tacoshy I'm trying to border the label element when radio is checked...